# like and favorite button for drupal

Tags: drupal, button, drupal-6

is there module for Drupal that user can like or unlike,and favorite the node?like stackoverflow's button?

tnx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Vote Up/Down module](https://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) works a lot like StackOverflow's Up/Down voting. The [Flag module](https://drupal.org/project/flag) can be made to work like StackOverflow's favorite feature.

Depending on your exact use case, you may also want to check out other modules that use the [Voting API module](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=drupal_core%3A87%20bs_project_sandbox%3A0&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc&text=%22Voting%20API%22) because there are lots of voting modules to choose from.

Comment: p.s. - You may also want to check out the Drupal Answers Beta site. The more people who use it, the better chance it has of making it past beta: http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: Vote Up/Down Module doesn't work with Drupal 7. Flag module isn't very configurable, to add features I used Drupal Like module on top of it but that doesn't seem to work with Drupal 7 either.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) and [fivestars](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar). I think that's what you are looking for.